# Making a wrapper over a generic Rep

Tags: haskell

I have a `Rep A` for some type that I modify using some `forall x. Rep A x -> F (Rep A) x` function where `F` is a type family. Let's say this wraps all the fields in a `Maybe`. What I want to do is to serialize that `F (Rep A)` to JSON. `aeson` provides functions that serialize generic types, but it doesn't provide the functions that operate on the actual generic representation.

To solve this problem I thought I could write something like this

```
newtype RepWrapper a = RepWrapper (F (Rep a))
```

with a generic instance

```
instance Generic a => Generic (RepWrapper a) where
    type Rep (RepWrapper a) = F (Rep a)
```

Then I can just use the `aeson` functions on this wrapped value.

The problem with the above is the extra type parameter that needs to be given to a `Rep`. There are three ways of doing that, as far as I can tell

```
newtype RepWrapper a = RepWrapper (forall x. F (Rep a) x)
data RepWrapper a = forall x. RepWrapper (F (Rep a) x)
newtype RepWrapper a x = RepWrapper (F (Rep a) x)
```

The first way lets me write the `from` function, the second way lets me write the `to` function and the third way seems useless.

Is there a way to define the wrapper so I can implement the whole `Generic` instance?

Comment: Just specify the extra variable as `()`, it's phantom anyway (unless you use `Generic1`, but that's seems quite unlikely). But if `F` is a type family, you should only need `ToJSON` instances for whatever types it maps to.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia You can't implement `to` _or_ `from` if you just specify it as `()`. Also, the type family maps a representation to a nearly identical representation, but with the fields (in the ˙K1` constructors) wrapper in a `Maybe`. There are no JSON instances for generic rep types, or at least their instances are not what I want.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I see better what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a data type `A`, `Generic` gives an isomorphism to a generic representation `Rep A`. Here we want to go the other way around. Given a generic representation `r` (here `r ~ F (Rep A)` for some `A`) we want a data type `B` such that `Rep B ~ r`. We define `B` as `Data r`:

```
data Data r = Data (r ())
```

The type parameter of `r :: * -> *` is phantom (actually, it's used by `Generic1`, and nobody uses `Generic1`), so we can instantiate it with anything, and we pick `()` as an arbitrary default.

We will need to express that phantom-ness as a constraint. One way is to take the conjunction of `Functor` and [`Contravariant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.4.1/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html).

```
type Bivariant f = (Functor f, Contravariant f)

phantom :: Bivariant f => f a -> f b  -- Data.Functor.Contravariant

instance Bivariant r => Generic (Data r) where
  type Rep (Data r) = r
  from (Data r) = phantom r
  to = Data . phantom
```

---

Also I have defined [`Data`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data-0.1.0.0/docs/Generic-Data-Types.html#t:Data) in *generic-data* where I kept the extra parameter instead of instantiating it, since it is actually cheap to do so.

Comment: Hah! `phantom` is a nice trick. Hopefully soon with quantified contexts we'll be able to require direct coercability.

Comment: Yes, that will be much nicer!